# How can i make my own error log file in wordpress? ( not with WP_DEBUG_LOG )

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i'm trying to create a wordpress plugin that imports some products and i want to be able to log any errors that occur, in a text file. I know that error logging already exists using:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

but i want to make my own file logging only the errors that occur from my plugin.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can log errors directly to a .log file in your plugin directory as mentioned here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/how-to-log-plugin-errors-to-plugin-error-log-file

If you insist to write to a 'text file' then you can use this method:
[Write from WordPress plugin to text file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559913/write-from-wordpress-plugin-to-text-file-with-php)

Make sure the folder you are writing the errors to has the correct permissions.

Comment: thk you, that was very helpfull... Also, in the first link you posted there is a comment that says that i can use `add_action('shutdown', 'custom_catch_fatals');` for fatal errors, but i amn't sure how can i pass the message of the fatal error inside the shutdown hook. maybe you know how can i do that?